# I want my javascript function output on a new tab

Tags: javascript, html

This is my simple javascript function to add two numbers, here this function displays output on my textfield whose id is c , I want to display output in a new tab

```
function add(){

    var a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    a = parseInt(a);
    var b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    b = parseInt(b);

    var c = a+b;

    document.getElementById("answer").value = c;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can go with [html5 localstorage cross tab communication](https://truongtx.me/2014/06/16/cross-tab-communication-using-html5-dom-storage/)

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new tab using:

```
window.open("Your-URL-here","_BLANK");
```

Comment: No not alert box ... New tab

Comment: I want my output in a new tab without using document.write

Comment: Well, provided answer will open desired url in new tab. How You mean *output in tab* ?... If You want to show output outside of current page (in your case in new tab - it's new page), You have to call some page where you'll show output.

Comment: You can send query string through the url and take the output to the new tab, just for the purpose of printing it.

Comment: generally it is the end user who decides if new windows should be opened in a tab or as a new window. You don't have control over that.

Comment: if you dont want to pass parmeter by query string, in opened page you can call window.parent.add(),and make add() function return value

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```js
function add(){
     var a = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    a = parseInt(a);
    var b = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    b = parseInt(b);

    var c = a+b;
 
    var w=window.open("")
    w.document.write(c)
  
}
```

```html
<input id="num1" type="number" />
<input id="num2" type="number" />
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add();return false" />
```